# Get the polygon created by moving a polygon

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I don't know if the process has a specific name. I want to get the polygon which is created by translating a polygon. Is there an algorithm for this. For example:
[image: Example].

Convex hull works for convex polygons but I want a general solution. Also I would be happy to hear if there is a way to get the polygon created by rotating.

Comment: So you want a solutions that works for concave polygons too?

Comment: @m69 Yes. Otherwise, convex hull works.

Comment: Your problem is underspecified.  What should be the result when e.g. the polygon is W-shaped and dragged horizontally?

Comment: @Gene Think of it like you take a W-shaped brush and paint horizontally. What shape you would get?

Comment: Rotation doesn't result in polygons but in curvilinear polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are looking for the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of your polygon and the line segment describing your movement.

The [CGAL library](http://www.cgal.org/) package [2D Minkowski Sums](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/) can compute them for instance.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Given the explanation you gave in comments, the straightforward approach is this:

```
Let v be a vector describing the linear movement
For each edge (p,q) in the polygon 
  construct quadrilateral (p, q, q+v, p+v)
Compute the union of all the quadrilaterals plus the original polygon
```

Computing polygon unions is a well-studied problem with efficient algorithms.

Comment: The union of the quadrilaterals *and* the original or translated polygon; otherwise if you only move the polygon slightly, you get a narrow outline.

Comment: @m69 Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Good algorithm, and seems easy to implement aswell. But seems like there is a more efficient solution. Thanks.